# How the Laravel controller method get the parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am studying some Laravel controller methods. In some controller methods, there are some parameters, but they are not coming from the route parameters. For example,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

How the Laravel controller method get the parameters? Who provided the parameter `$request`? How Laravel differentiate route parameters and this type of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is called dependency injection. Before Laravel calls the `store()` method, it analyses it's signature with [PHPs Reflection capabilities](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and resolves all parameters that type-hint a class through the IoC container. That's how you get the current request injected automatically.

After those parameters are resolved, the route parameters will be passed. Because the type-hinted arguments are resolved first it doesn't really matter whether they are at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of your argument list. The only case that matters is with optional route parameters:

Doesn't work:

```
public function store($foo = 'bar', Request $request){
```

Works:

```
public function store(Request $request, $foo = 'bar'){
```

Answer (score 1):

These are injected by Laraval IoC eg Inversion of Control containers and called method injection. This is one of the things that makes Laravel so amazing.

When you typehint a variable then Laravel will create one for you depending on a context.

More info about it from http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#introduction